# Не могу вызвать OnItemClickListener для кастомного списка

Tags: java, android

ItemListFragment:

```
public class ItemsListFragment extends Fragment {
private BoxAdapter adapterItems;
private ListView lvItems;

public static OnItemSelectedListener listener;

public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(Item i);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
        listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement ItemsListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create arraylist from item fixtures
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    String stat = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("stat");
    switch (stat) {
        case "adr":
            Item item = new Item();
            items = item.getItems(getContext());
            break;
        case "deladr":
            Item itemDel = new Item();
            items = itemDel.getDeletedItems(getContext());
            break;
    }
    adapterItems = new BoxAdapter(getContext(), items);
    //adapterItems = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, items);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items_list, container,
            false);
    // Bind adapter to ListView
    lvItems = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    lvItems.setAdapter(adapterItems);
    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View item, int position,
                                long rowId) {
            // Retrieve item based on position
            Item i = adapterItems.getItem(position);
            // Fire selected event for item
            listener.onItemSelected(i);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    lvItems.setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}
}
```

BoxAdapter:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Item> objects;
BoxAdapter adapter;

public BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> OrderModels) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = OrderModels;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    adapter = this;
}

// кол-во элементов
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

// элемент по позиции
@Override
public Item getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

// id по позиции
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// пункт списка
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_item, parent, false);
    }

    OrderModel p = getOrderModel(position).getTitle();

    try {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adress)).setText(p.adress);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fio)).setText(p.fio);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tel)).setText(p.tel + " Time: " + p.time);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("TimeTranslationError", ex.getMessage());
    }

    Button btnCh = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_change);
    btnCh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            WorkSQLite.UpdateOrders(ctx, getOrderModel(position).getTitle().id);
            objects.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    view.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View t) {
            // Retrieve item based on position
            Item i = getItem(position);
            // Fire selected event for item
            listener.onItemSelected(i);
        }
    });

    /*LinearLayout contentText = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
    contentText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //ItemsListFragment().listener.onItemSelected(getItem(position));
            new ItemsListActivity().onItemSelected(getItem(position));
        }
    });*/

    return view;
}

// товар по позиции
Item getOrderModel(int position) {
    return ((Item) getItem(position));
}

}
```

ItemsListActivity:

```
public class ItemsListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
private boolean isTwoPane = false;
public String stat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_items);
    stat = getIntent().getStringExtra("stat");
    determinePaneLayout();
}

private void determinePaneLayout() {
    FrameLayout fragmentItemDetail = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flDetailContainer);
    if (fragmentItemDetail != null) {
        isTwoPane = true;
        ItemsListFragment fragmentItemsList =
                (ItemsListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentItemsList);
        fragmentItemsList.setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }
}

public void ClearCar() {
    ArrayList<OrderModel> OrderModels = WorkSQLite.ReadOrders(this);

    if (OrderModels.size() > 0) {

        ArrayList<OrderModel> result = new ArrayList<OrderModel>();
        for (OrderModel object : OrderModels) {
            if (object.getValue("status").equals("2")) result.add(object);
        }

        if (result.size() == OrderModels.size()) {
            new GoodsFromDB.UpdateGoods().execute(getFilesDir().getPath().toString());
            WorkSQLite.DeleteAllOrders(this);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(Item item) {
    if (isTwoPane) { // single activity with list and detail
        // Replace frame layout with correct detail fragment
        ItemDetailFragment fragmentItem = ItemDetailFragment.newInstance(item);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.flDetailContainer, fragmentItem);
        ft.commit();
    } else { // separate activities
        // launch detail activity using intent
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("item", item);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

}
```

Не знаю что делать

Пытаюсь вызвать обработчик OnItemClickListener в ItemListFragment и он просто не реагирует поверх кастомного адаптера

В адаптере задаю OnClickListener для view, при нажатии на элемент списка, вылетает с exeption android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001a

Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте слушатель прямо в адаптере. Корневому элементу айтема присвойте `id`, найдите его в методе `getView()` и присвойте слушатель. Не забудьте добавить в корневой элемента айтема

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: я только начинаю, подробнее можно как-нибудь?

Comment: я дал корневому элементу id, и назначаю ему слушатель в getView(). Выдаёт exeption android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001a, как описано выше